# Greatest common factor

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

"The collection $\lbrace 8, 9, 12\rbrace$ is a set of three positive integers with the property that, given any
two of these integers, their greatest common factor (gcf) is equal to their difference:

- $\text{gcd}(8,9)=1=9−8$;
- $\text{gcd}(8,12)=4=12−8$;
- $\text{gcd}(9,12)=3=12−9$.

Can you find a set of four integers with the same property? What about a set of $n$ integers?"

I have come up with more examples of two integer pairs (example: $\lbrace 84,112 \rbrace$) but can't seem to work out a  'formula' or a general case to build up to the $4$ integer case or even the $n$ integer case.

Comment: $\{6, 8, 9, 12\}$?

Comment: [python search](https://tio.run/##dVDNjoMgED7LU3DaQJaa7fbSNOFJmsZQAYtBMDAm@vTuqK3tZTnxDd/f0E/wiOF07tM8u66PCagDkyBGn8lz0Cl4EJtiR@vovanBxZDp81EbqwYP2tWwcewQ6lX@YiSjh9qQLK/MiZZTGxPFC3XhHVX2KSILWFKhMewojj94uEimNwrkL6fOrj3KptarjZTqnpk7tPxGtPxowbIBTj5C8oUU@upupdKatXwB7QYcJyiklo0icGRhhjeBjWgeEBbJwJACHUmRK7mtwZhX3V0rOorpMn5NXLDFe1tqSRs5P2ADNCHFPszVYmcriVHfSMc4xBhn14dXkK3WPg1b27zVu9i7DNj6f/mu2f7xJM6LU59cANagks/zHw): $\{36, 40, 42, 48, 45\}$, $\{210, 216, 224, 225, 240, 220\}$

Comment: Hints: from 8,9,12; try to construct sequences of arbitrarily large three numbers. Second, consider that your sequence is actually $0,8,9,12$ (even though $0$ is not allowed, it’s unimportant) – and construct like in the first part a sequence with larger (hence nonzero) numbers, but which is similar.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099305/are-there-arbitrarily-large-sets-s-of-natural-integers-such-that-the-differenc/2182924#2182924)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create sets as big as you want and this can be proved by induction:

For $n=2$ you can take set $\{1,2\}$ as the solution. Now the induction step:

Now suppose that such set exists for some $n$ and denote that set with $S_n=\{a_i\mid i=1,2,...,n\}$.

Calculate all differencies $d_{jk}$ between all pairs of elements $a_j<a_k$ picked from the set $S_n$. Notice that:

$$d_{jk}=a_k-a_j=\gcd(a_j,a_k)\tag{1}$$

Find the least common multiple for all $d_{jk},a_i$:

$$L=LCM \left(\{d_{jk}=a_k-a_j\mid 1\le j <k\le n\}\cup \{a_i\mid i=1,2,...,n\}\right)\tag{2}$$

Check the following set with $n+1$ elements:

$$S_{n+1}=\{L\}\cup\{L+a_i\mid i=1,2,...,n\} $$

**Firstly**, take any two elements from the extend set different from $L$:

$$\gcd(L+a_j, L+a_k)=\gcd(L+a_j, a_k-a_j)=\gcd(L+a_j, d_{jk})$$

According to (1) and (2) we know that $d_{jk}\mid a_j$ and $d_{jk}\mid L$. Therefore:

$$\gcd(L+a_j, L+a_k)=d_{jk}=a_k-a_j=(L+a_k)-(L+a_j)$$

**Secondly**, if you pick $L$ and $L+a_j$:

$$\gcd(L, L+a_j)=\gcd(L, a_j)=a_j=(L+a_j)-L$$

The last is obvious as per definition of $L$ ($a_j\mid L$).

Now, the fun part. Start with:

$$S_2=\{1,2\}$$

and apply the algorithm described above, you get the following sequence of solutions with rapidly growing numbers:

$$S_3=\{2, 3, 4\}$$

$$S_4=\{12, 14, 15, 16\}$$

$$S_5=\{1680, 1692, 1694, 1695, 1696\}$$

$$S_6=\{343319185440, 343319187120, 343319187132, 343319187134, 343319187135, \
343319187136\}$$

$$S_7=\{118295944058236539689200180716000759951728985298370880, \
118295944058236539689200180716000759951729328617556320, \
118295944058236539689200180716000759951729328617558000, \
118295944058236539689200180716000759951729328617558012, \
118295944058236539689200180716000759951729328617558014, \
118295944058236539689200180716000759951729328617558015, \
118295944058236539689200180716000759951729328617558016\}$$

So the method is far from optimal and finding the "smallest" set for a given $n$ is still a challenge. But you can create as long a sequence as you want.

(I have solved a similar but not completely identical problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2764379/set-of-n-natural-numbers-a-i-such-that-if-a-j-lt-a-k-then-a-k-a-j-m/2809815#2809815) but the same logic is applicable here too.)

Comment: Great answer! It's somewhat surprising such sets can be arbitrarily large! The defining property seems very restrictive at first glance.